# Storing Access token, Google+ integration Android App

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, access-token, google-api-client

I am new to **android** and i started with importing sample app from GooglePlayServices in the android SDK. 
The app "Plus" allows me to sign-in using G+ credentials. The Sample code is using **GoogleApiClient**.

This authenticates the App only on client. How do i send access token to my **server** Or store the **access token** in to my **shared preferences**??

Someone please Explain me which file i should add access token code to.?

Comment: are you getting the `AccessToken` ?

Comment: No, i will have to request for it in a background thread. Can you help me in doing that and finally storing it.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are able to login to GooglePlus successfully.Do something like below to get the AccessToken and store it using `SharedPreference`,

```
SharedPreferences SharedPreference;    
Editor editor;

    private class GetGoogleAuthTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>  {
             @Override
             protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                 String token = null;

                 try {
                     token=GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(User_SignUp.this,Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient),"oauth2:"+Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN+" "+Scopes.PLUS_ME); //Change the permissions as per your need.
                 } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                     // Network or server error, try later
                     Log.e(TAG, transientEx.toString());
                 } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                     // Recover (with e.getIntent())
                     Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    // Intent recover = e.getIntent();
                    // startActivityForResult(recover, REQUEST_CODE_TOKEN_AUTH);
                 } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                     // The call is not ever expected to succeed
                     // assuming you have already verified that 
                     // Google Play services is installed.
                     Log.e(TAG, authEx.toString());
                 }

                 return token;
             }

             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(String token) {

                 if(token!=null)
                 {
                  Log.i(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + token);
                  SharedPreference = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TokenPreference", 0); 
                  editor = SharedPreference.edit();
                  editor.putString("access_token",token);                               
                  editor.commit();                      

                 }

             }

         }
```

Use below snippet where you need to get the accesstoken,

```
new GetGoogleAuthTask().execute();
```

Comment: Can you tell me.. How do i send this obtained token to my Server ?

Comment: You just need to send it like simple string data only. Read some tutorial about how to send data to server using HTTP.

Comment: I know that..! but in java i wanted some implementation demo. I have actually a node server running. Now i want to output this obtained token in my console atleast. Just below tokenValue=new GetGoogleAuthTask().execute() i need to send it to server right ?

Comment: One more thing i wanted to ask. I need to write a code to validate access token on my server. So how to do this? My server code may not be in java. right?